# g++ doesn't work with Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I was working on a Java code for compiling a program.

So the user can choose the file to be compiled, and then the program runs by its own g++.

Looking on the net, in particular StackOverFlow, I've decided to use this code:

```
//Set a FileChoose called fc, got the file path (filePath) and the directory path (dirPath), then:
ProcessBuilder process=null;
try {
    process = new ProcessBuilder("g++", filePath, " -o "+dirPath+"/a.out").start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error compiling file");
    Logger.getLogger(Nuovo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The point is that it doesn't return any error, and when I check if the file is compiled there is just nothing.

Any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: read the error stream of your process, to get more informations

Comment: This code does not compile. `ProcessBuilder.start()` returns a `Process`, but you assign it to a variable of `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before, I've been a little busy latly.
The point was that there wasn't any error.
As @JornVernee suggested the problem was that I was returning a Process to a ProcessBuilder. I solved that in this way: Process pr;
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
try{
    pr=rt.exec(String []);
} catch (IOException e){}
Where the argument of the exec() functions is a String array which contains something (depending on the need) like {"bin/bash", "-c", comand}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read the output of the program to see what errors it produced.

My guess is it will say something like.

```
File not found:  -o dir/a.out
```

Note, you have specified that the `" -o "+dirPath+"/a.out"` is a single argument.  This is like writing

```
g++ $filePath ' -o dir/a.out'
```

Perhaps what you intended was

```
new ProcessBuilder("g++", filePath, "-o", dirPath+"/a.out").start();
```

Why doesn't Java act like a shell and parse your argument? Because it passes the argument to the system call `exec` so it really doesn't do anything C++ wouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the apache commons exec library located at : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/download_exec.cgi. The java process exec has few major gaps: if the native command send you a message the java process will not parse the message and also will block the execution of the java program.

example:

- you call from java the following command: del *.*
- the system will send you back a confirmation message: Are you sure (Y/N)?
- The java ProcessBuilder will not parse the confirmation message and it will block the execution of the program.

For that reason I recommend the apache commons exec library which has also a good documentation https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html.